# Need to remove "hindu" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-deletion

I edited out 3 questions recently where OP used [hindu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hindu) which makes no sense as site itself is about hinduism and hence, I would request a moderator to delete the flag before it goes viral.

List of questions I removed the tag from

- [Why can we eat 'living' plants but not 'living' animals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/why-can-we-eat-living-plants-but-not-living-animals)
- [Why Hindu Saint are targeted very badly in India?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/544/why-hindu-saint-are-targeted-very-badly-in-india)
- [Every thing in Hindu culture is based on the science?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/why-can-we-eat-living-plants-but-not-living-animals)

Currently the tag shows that 3 questions asked this year, I am not sure if there is a cron job to delete the tags which has no questions asked with, if thats the thing, it will be deleted, if not than I would the mod to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added [hindu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hindu) / [hindus](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hindus) to the blacklist, as these should be assumed to apply to most questions asked here.

Comment: Great, would drop in few more if I feel they should be black listed

Comment: Post separate discussions if you encounter more, please.

Comment: Ya sure.. .. . .