# Need some Tag standardization

Tags: discussion, tags

[Recently I posted a question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/need-to-remove-hindu-tag) to remove [hindu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hindu) as it makes no sense, same way, some users are tagging questions with hindi words, so we have to decide whether we are sticking with those, or we are going to mark them as synonyms?

Personally I think we should tag in English as much as possible, unfortunately we cannot use in few like gods names, for hell and heaven etc, but some tags are just getting duplicated badly, for example..

**What they are using**               **What should be there** *(They are already using some of these too)*

[jyotish](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jyotish) / [astrology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrology)                [astrologer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrologer) / [astrology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrology)

[jiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jiva)                                        [life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life)

[afterlife](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afterlife)                                   [after-life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-life) *(As we are using a - for [life-span](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life-span))*

[yamalo](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yamalo) / [yamaloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yamaloka)                [yamaloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yamaloka)

*(I don't think this suits well here, so we should stick with [yamaloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yamaloka))*

[cows](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cows) / [animals](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals)                    [animals](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals)

[buddhism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buddhism) / [the-buddha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-buddha)           Off topic as we have a separate site for that now and for some reason 
                                                  we need to ask a cross religion question than we should consider                                                   writing [gautama-buddha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gautama-buddha) instead of just <s>[the-buddha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-buddha)</s> 
                                                  or better refer [other-religions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-religions) <sup>[1]</sup>

[dhoti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dhoti) / [dress](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dress)                       [dress](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dress)

[beef](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beef) / [food](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food)                         [food](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food)

[atma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atma)                                       [aatma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aatma) / [soul](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul)

[festivals](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/festivals) / [diwali](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diwali) / [holi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holi)      [festivals](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/festivals)

[bhagavad-gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavad-gita) /

[bhagvada-gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagvada-gita)                           [bhagavad-gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavad-gita)

[deva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deva) / [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods)                        [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods)

[vrata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrata) / [fasting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fasting)                     [fasting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fasting)

[other-religions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-religions) /

[buddhism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buddhism) / [islam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam) /

[christianity](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity)                              [other-religions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-religions) <sup>[1]</sup>

So as you see, so many tags are used on the left hand side are already duplicated, can be called as synonyms, but with two different languages, so please decide are we going to stick with the Hindi versions or with the English ones.

<sup>Please edit the post only if you are good with formatting skills as too many `&nbsp;` are used which may spoil the formatting, so don't do it unless you are sure enough to handle the formatting, a comment will be helpful too :)</sup>

---

<sup>Don't get confused with the tags at the bottom, they are not the part of the actual answer :)</sup>

Comment: many of our Hindu philosophers don't know what a word is known as in English.(_some don't even respect english_). IMO, it will be better to make synonyms keeping both in Hindi and English.

Comment: hell and yamaloka are different.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Define the difference by answering so that we get some clear ideas, yamaloka = Narak, and Narak = Hell

Comment: Its already discussed here [Wha is Yamlokam? How is it different from Naraka?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/461/what-is-yamlokam-how-is-it-different-from-naraka)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Edited out the wrong option ;) thanks for the comment

Comment: Once we have moderators, it will be easy for them to do tag cleanup like this. I recommend that we wait (just a few days) for moderator appointment and then have them take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would be antithetical to scholarship to translate these tags into English. The Sanskrit versions should include multiple English translations if possible so that they show up no matter what is typed in.

---

Also, Philosophy students in the West are taught to think of many Sanskrit terms as Eastern counterparts to key ancient Greek & Latin terms. The pedagogical efficacy of this aside, it is probably beneficial to add relevant classical philosophy terms in italics to the descriptions as well. E.g., most English speakers cannot decide what is the difference between "spirit" and "soul," but scholars will understand

> *ātman* : *psyche* :: *prāṇa* : *pneuma*.